# Se pueden representar datos en una tabla en el output de Pandas?

Tags: python, tablas

```
simar = pd.read_csv(
"SIMAR.csv",
delim_whitespace=True,   # delimitado por espacios en blanco
usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,6),  # columnas que queremos usar
skiprows=82,  # saltar las 99 primeras líneas
names=['año','mes','dia','hora','Hmo', 'Tp'],
)
```

Con esta exportacion de datos se obtiene una DF del estilo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
simar.Hmo = simar.Hmo.loc[simar.Hmo>0] #elimnimos los valores negatuivos (-99.9) 
simar.Tp = simar.Tp.loc[simar.Tp>0] #elimnimos los valores negatuivos (-99.9)
```

Ahora mi idea era crear un bucleo que vaya tomando los datos que cumplan 2 condiciones de pertenecer a un intervalo determinado en la columna de Hmo y a otro intervalo en la columna de Tp, para ir metiendo la longitud de la columna Tp en cada una de las celdas de la tabla.

```
for i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]:
    for j in [0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5]:
        a=simar[simar.Tp.between(i,i+0.99) & simar.Hmo.between(j,j+0.49)]
        numdatos=len(a.Tp)
        celdatabla[i,j]=numdatos #La idea aqui es meter este valor en su celda correspondiente, 
                             #la celda [i,j] si lo tratásemos como una matriz.
```

El caso es que no sé como crear una tabla.

Sobre la tabla: busco que tenga una fila primera como título con los intervalos de Tp (0-1,1-2,2-3,3-4,4-5,...) y una columna primera como titulo con los intervalos de Hmo (0-0.5,0.5-1,1-1.5,2,...). Para ir metiendo los datos de numdato en su celda (por ejemplo en la celda del intervalo 1-2 de Tp y 2.5-3 de Hmo.

EN la siguiente imagen muestro una tabla del estilo al que me gustaría llegar.

Muchas gracias

[image: Tabla ejemplo de lo que quiero conseguir]

Comment: No se entiende lo que preguntas. ¿Quieres que padas te muestre una tabla como la que has puesto? ¿O quieres que haga una gráfica con ellos? (pues dices "estilo histograma") ¿Cómo son los datos que ya tienes, siguen la estructura de esa tabla, o son diferentes y quieres a partir de ellos generar esa estructura? Estaría bien que pusieras algo del código que estás usando y no sólo la tabla que quieres al final

Comment: A ver si ahora me he explicado mejor. Gracias!

Comment: Ya reedité la pregunta @abulafia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo que el problema es ir asignando valores a los lugares de la tabla, y no el formato final de la misma, que parece más bien creado con LaTeX (aunque con esfuerzo posiblemente se podría emular un resultado similar con pandas también), y que tampoco necesitas la columna y fila finales que ponen el "Total".

Centrándonos sólo en el problema de generar la zona "central" de la tabla, la que tiene los números, tenemos que resolver un par de asuntos:

- Nombrar automáticamente las columnas y el índice de la tabla, para que sean "0-0.5", "0.5-1", etc. (sin mucho esfuerzo tambíen podrían nombrarse "[0, 0.5)", "[0.5, 1)", etc.)
- Generar los datos que irían en cada una de esas celdas
- Asignar cada dato a la correspondiente celda.

Se me ocurre la siguiente solución:

1. Crear un array numpy de ceros, de las dimensiones correctas y en base a él crear un dataframe que tenga todo ceros en su interior, pero que tenga los nombres de filas y columnas ya correctos
2. Por modularizar mejor el código, escribir una función que reciba `i,j` como parámetros (los extremos del intervalo a considerar) y devuelva el número adecuado.
3. Iterar en un par de bucles similares a los que planteas por `i, j` para ir computando los valores y asignándolos a la celda correspondiente del dataframe

Así que vamos con cada parte

### Creación del dataframe con ceros

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

bins_i = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
bins_j = [0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5]
row_names = [f"{ini}-{fin}" for ini, fin in zip(bins_i, bins_i[1:] + [bins_i[-1]+1])]
col_names = [f"{ini}-{fin}" for ini, fin in zip(bins_j, bins_j[1:] + [bins_j[-1]+.5])]

matriz = np.zeros((len(bins_i), len(bins_j)), dtype=int)
df = pd.DataFrame(matriz, columns=col_names, index=row_names)
```

Como ves preparo en un par de variables los límites de intervalo por los que se pretende iterar. Uso esas listas para crear otras listas con los nombres que tendrán las columnas y filas. El truco aquí ha sido usar `zip()` para emparejar cada elemento de la lista con el siguiente, usando como primer parámetro por ejemplo `bins_i` y  como segundo `bins_i[1:]` que lo desplaza una unidad. Ya que el segundo parámetro tendría menos elementos que el primero le añado uno extra sumando 1 al último. Análogamente para `bins_j`.

El dataframe resultante del código anterior será:

[image: Dataframe ceros]

### Función que computa los valores

En tu caso sería:

```
def computar_valor(i,j):
    a=simar[simar.Tp.between(i,i+0.99) & simar.Hmo.between(j,j+0.49)]
    numdatos=len(a.Tp)
    return numdatos
```

Ya que yo no tengo tus datos, para poder generar algo y ver si funciona, implemento una función "tonta" que simplemente retorna `int((i+j)*2)`

### Bucle que rellena la tabla

Para poder acceder a una columna o fila por su índice en lugar de por su nombre, se usa `df.iloc[num_fila, num_columna]`. Por tanto a la hora de iterar necesitamos también un contador de fila y de columna. Usando `enumerate()` podemos obtenerlos.

```
for num_fila, i in enumerate(bins_i):
  for num_columna,j in enumerate(bins_j):
    valor = computar_valor(i,j)
    df.iloc[num_fila, num_columna] = valor
```

Con mi implementación *fake* de `computar_valor()` sale la tabla siguiente:

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Muchas gracias por todo!